# C#- Check if stack has enough free memory

Tags: c#, pointers, stack, unsafe, stackalloc

Rather than heap allocating and pinning a pointer table I need as a method local, I want to `stackalloc` it wherever possible. This is critical code, in fact it's arguably the most critical section of my system, so I do not want to simply catch an overflow and then reallocate it on the heap and hand a pointer back over. I'd like to check if there is enough available stack memory **before** deciding whether to call `stackalloc`, or manually allocating some unmanaged memory if there is not enough space available.

Tl;dr; how do I check how much memory is available on the current thread's stack? Or alternatively, is there some other way to (performantly) have `stackalloc` handle the case where there is not enough free memory to complete?

Comment: This feels like a XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . What concrete problem are you experiencing currently? It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your work so far.

Comment: @mjwills to be honest, from other reading I've seen these unsafe questions devolve into usage arguments pretty quickly so I was trying to be as specific as possible to avoid the general case. That aside, there really isn't anything to add; I'm anticipating a possible edge case where stackalloc will fail, and I want to catch that ahead of time by manually verifying that there is enough free stack memory before making the call, otherwise I'll manually handle the memory.

Comment: I need the memory either way; stackalloc has benched to be more performant for this use case, but on that edge case if it fails, I still need to complete the method, it just means that I need to get the memory by some other means, and I don't want the overhead of unwinding the stack from throwing it in a catch block as a check due to the performance requirements.